# How to see all command or subprogram of git project?

Tags: git

I don't know how to list all command or subprogram that the git project have. Use `git help` or `man git` only show a little number of command. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls /usr/libexec/git-core/
git-[TAB]
```

In git, all commands are stored as executables (or symlinks) beginning with `git-`. So these two commands together will show you the possible subprograms.

Answer (score 2):

The most correct way is only

```
git help --all
```